# Use mathematical induction to prove $ (2n)!\geq 2^n(n!)^2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: induction

I am trying to use mathematical induction to prove

$$(2n)!\ge2^n(n!)^2\quad\text{for }n\in\mathbb{N}$$

I am stuck at the $n=k+1$ point.

Comment: To the OP:  it'll be well worth your while to learn a little TeX.  There are tutorials available.

Comment: sorry; first time posting with math equations!

Comment: No need to apologize.  There's a bit of a learning curve to TeX, but it's really pretty easily climbed.  It all starts with the dollar sign....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the $k+1$ step we obtain $(2k+2)!\geq 2^{k+1}(k+1)!^2$, which is equivalent to:
$(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!\geq 2^k2(k+1)^2(k)!^2$. By our inductive hypothesis the largest that $2^k(k)!^2$ could possibly be is $(2k)!$, so we can replace $2^k(k)!^2$ on the left hand side with $(2k)!$, and cancel the term from both sides to obtain $(2k+2)(2k+1)\geq 2(k+1)!^2$. Doing some basic algebra we obtain $4k^2+6k+2\geq 2k^2+2k+1$, which is true by inspection (note that the coefficients of the polynomial on the left hand side are all larger than those on the right hand side, and so for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ this will hold).

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! Your explanation cleared up a lot of things. I'm just wondering why this is possible when you said " By our inductive hypothesis the largest that 2k(k)!2 could possibly be is (2k)!, so we can replace 2k(k)!2 on the left hand side with (2k)!, and cancel the term from both sides to obtain (2k+2)(2k+1)≥2(k+1)!2. "

Comment: oh and did you mean right hand side for "we can replace 2k(k)!2 on the left hand side with (2k)!"?

Comment: It is possible because we assume that $(2k)!\geq 2^n(n!)^2$ after we show the base case at $n=1$, and the reasoning is that if the relation $\geq$ holds when they are equal, then it will also hold for any case where $(2k)!> 2^k(k!)^2$.

Comment: To answer you second question, yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

$(2(n+1))! = (2n+2)! = (2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2) \geq 2^n\cdot (n!)^2\cdot (2n+1)(2n+2) > 2^n(n!)^2\cdot (n+1)(2n+2) = 2^{n+1}((n+1)!)^2$. Done !

Comment: hi! thanks for answering... I'm just wondering if you can explain how you reached the answer? where did (2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2) come from? and where did (2n+1)(2n+2) from 2n⋅(n!)2⋅(2n+1)(2n+2)?

Comment: $(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$ by the definition of $K!=K.(K-1)!$

Answer (score 1):

Induction is not really needed here. Observe that
$${(2n!) \over (n!)^2} = {2n \over n}{2n-1 \over n- 1} ...{n \over 1}$$
Each factor is at least $2$ so the product is at least $2^n$.

---

Hint for an inductive proof: Let $a_n  = {(2n)! \over (n!)^2} $. Then 
$${a_{n+1} \over a_n} = {(2(n+1))! \over (2n)!} { (n!)^2 \over (n+1)!^2 }$$
$$ = { (2n + 2)(2n + 1) \over (n+1)(n+1)}$$
$$= 2{2n + 1 \over n + 1}$$
$$> 2$$
This should be highly helpful for an inductive proof.

Comment: it is an induction question though

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were being asked to use induction or you were just asked the question and you were attempting an inductive proof. At any rate, I still think this is worth pointing out.

Comment: I added an inductive argument